# Populating the drop down list with static values in odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I want to populate a dropdown with static values from 1-9 (to assign priority to a manufacturer) in Odoo 8. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: We know how to populate the dropdown list through the database but have no idea how to populate it with static values and we are new to odoo !! Also after selecting the value from the drop down we wanted to store the value in the database coulmn!  Could u please help us out?

Answer (score 1):

```
priority = fields.Selection([
        ('1','1'),('2','2'),('3','3'),('4','4'),
        ('5','5'),('6','6'),('7','7'),('8','8'),
        ('9','9'),     
    ], string='Priority')
```

add this field 'priority' in xml too.

It will add a dropdown field with static values from 1-9.